# Using kubernetes client to run a script on pod and get outout

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a python script using which I need to run on a container and get output. Now i am able to get the container name as below:-

```python
config.load_kube_config()
configuration.assert_hostname = False
# config.load_incluster_config()

contexts, active_context = config.list_kube_config_contexts()
contexts = [context["name"] for context in contexts]
cluster1 = contexts[0]
cluster2 = contexts[1]

print(f"First cluster is: {cluster1}")
print(f"Second cluster is: {cluster2}")

client1 = client.CoreV1Api(
    api_client=config.new_client_from_config(context=cluster1)
)
client2 = client.CoreV1Api(
    api_client=config.new_client_from_config(context=cluster2)
)

for i in client1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace).items:
    if "cassandra-0" in i.metadata.name:
        pod1_name = f"{i.metadata.name}"
        print(F"Cassandra Pod Name in NA: {pod1_name}")
```

Now output i get is:

```
Cassandra Pod Name in NA: cassandra-0
```

But now when i add a command:

```python
        # Calling exec and waiting for response
        exec_command = ['nodetool status']
        resp = stream(client2.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec,
                  pod1_name,
                  namespace,
                  command=exec_command,
                  stderr=True, stdin=False,
                  stdout=True, tty=False)
        print("Response: " + resp)
        resp.close()
```

Its giving me below error now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\kubernetes\stream\ws_client.py", line 512, in websocket_call
    client = WSClient(configuration, url, headers, capture_all)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\kubernetes\stream\ws_client.py", line 65, in __init__
    self.sock = create_websocket(configuration, url, headers)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\kubernetes\stream\ws_client.py", line 478, in create_websocket
    websocket.connect(url, **connect_opt)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 248, in connect
    self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, url, *addrs, **options)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 57, in handshake
    status, resp = _get_resp_headers(sock)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 148, in _get_resp_headers
    raise WebSocketBadStatusException("Handshake status %d %s", status, status_message, resp_headers)
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 400 Bad Request
```

Any idea what am doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't post images of text; just post the text itself, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: `stream(client2.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec` is the `client2` is expected here? and can you try with `exec_command = ["/bin/sh", "-c", "nodetool status"]`

Answer (score 0):

The only issue in the code that I notice is that the code looking for the pod in the `cluster0` and executes the command in the `cluster1` i.e `client2.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec,`

Here is the working example

```
from click import command
from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes.stream import stream
config.load_kube_config()

contexts, active_context = config.list_kube_config_contexts()
contexts = [context["name"] for context in contexts]
print (contexts)
cluster1 = contexts[4]
cluster2 = contexts[1]

print(f"First cluster is: {cluster1}")
print(f"Second cluster is: {cluster2}")

client1 = client.CoreV1Api(
    api_client=config.new_client_from_config(context=cluster1)
)
client2 = client.CoreV1Api(
    api_client=config.new_client_from_config(context=cluster2)
)

for i in client1.list_namespaced_pod("vault").items:
    print(i.metadata.name)
    if "vault-1" in i.metadata.name:
        pod1_name = f"{i.metadata.name}"
        print(F"Cassandra Pod Name in NA: {pod1_name}")
        # Calling exec and waiting for response
        exec_command = ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo $HOSTNAME && vault status"]
        resp = stream(client1.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec,
                  pod1_name,
                  "vault",
                  command=exec_command,
                  stderr=True, stdin=False,
                  stdout=True, tty=False)
        print("Response: " + resp)
```

[image]